# Issue running SSL-enabled TCP server under mono

Tags: c#, mono, certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I'm developing an application which requires SSL encryption between the client and server, and needs to run under Windows and in Ubuntu under Mono.  At the moment, the server and client pair works fine in Windows, but when the client connects to the server, the server returns this error:

> Error:  The authentication or decryption has failed.   at
>   Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback
>   (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0

I'm loading the certificate like this:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("server.pfx", "<password>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Current Mono versions do not support SSL connections as server without client certificates.

Either use a client certificate or apply a patch to the source code.

You can find an example of how to do that in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171536/mono-httplistener-client-certificate).